# DDD: Pattern for submitting and approving contracts

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm working on an app where the following requirements exist:

- A user submits some data in a form and this gets persisted as a "Draft Copy."
- On the other end, an approver reads it and takes some action (Approve, Reject, etc)
- If the approver approves the Draft Copy, it becomes a Contract and the two parties are legally bound. The original submitter can go back and make changes to the Draft Copy, and resubmit. When the approver approves the most recent version, the existing Contract is replaced with this new one.

What I'm struggling with is we are trying to employ DDD on our project and no solution really "feels right." We are all pretty inexperienced with modern DDD, so finding the right model is quite confusing.

This is not a Document Management problem. There is always exactly one Draft Copy which the submitter works with, and sometimes there is a Contract which neither party can edit (edits are performed by resubmitting the Draft Copy with changes). For these purposes, the fields in these two domain concepts are identical.

Is there some design pattern or DDD friendly solution that can be applied here?

Comment: Right now we are just discussing design options. We're considering three things: Attaching a Contract to a DraftCopy; keeping a DraftCopy as a value object within a Contract, and not really employing any specific DDD technique and instead just correlating the two objects with some kind of common ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about what do you want here, but I suggest you should look at the [EventSourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) pattern. It very useful for tracking change of a domain object.
Follow Martin Fowler:

> Event Sourcing ensures that all changes to application state are
>   stored as a sequence of events. Not just can we query these events, we
>   can also use the event log to reconstruct past states, and as a
>   foundation to automatically adjust the state to cope with retroactive
>   changes.

And Greg Young:

> Another problem with the having of two models is that it is
>   necessarily more work. One must create the code to save the current
>   state of the objects and one must write the code to generate and
>   publish the events. No matter how you go about doing these things it
>   cannot possibly be easier than only publishing events, even if you had
>   something that made storing current state completely trivial to say a
>   document storage, there is still the effort of bringing that into the
>   project.

—Greg Young -

When a user submit a 'Draft copy' it should be raised an event and store it into the `EventSourcing`.
Another user raise another 'Draft copy' will be captured by `EventSourcing` object and mark it as new version. How to make it different you should apply DDD. A document object is a `Domain` object and have an identifier.

It will be easy for querying and update state from `Eventsourcing` for each versions of entity, and take back version of an object.

You can take more reference about `EventSourcing` from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591559.aspx).

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, we are actually planning to use event sourcing already for all of our aggregates and maybe this is part of the solution.

Comment: +1. Many thanks. This is first time I know about EventSourcing.